# Bash: How to record highest memory/cpu consumption during execution of a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a function in a bash script that executes a long process called runBatch.  Basically runBatch takes a file as an argument and loads the contents into a db.  (runBatch is just a wrapper function for a database command that loads the content of the file)

My function has a loop that looks something like the below, where I am currently recording start time and elapsed time for the process to variables.

```
for batchFile in `ls $batchFilesDir`
do
     echo "Batch file is $batchFile"  
     START_TIME=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
     runBatch $batchFile
     ELAPSED_TIME=$(($(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))-START_TIME))
     IN_SECONDS=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\",${ELAPSED_TIME}/1000}")
done
```

Then I am writing some information on each batch (such as time, etc.) to a table in a html page I am generating.

How would I go about recording the highest memory/cpu usage *while the runBatch is running*, along with the time, etc?

Any help appreciated.

Edit: I managed to get this done.  I added a wrapper script around this script that runs this script in the background.  I pass it's PID with $! to another script in the wrapper script that monitors the processes CPU and Memory usage with top every second.  I compile everything into a html page at the end when the PID is no longer alive.  Cheers for the pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the PID of the process using $!,

```
runBatch $batchFile &
myPID=$!
```

and then you can run a `top -b -p $myPID` to print out a ticking summary of CPU.

Comment: good tip, but then he won't be able to get the elapsedTime. :-/ Good luck to all.

Comment: I don't know how to get the elapsed time if I do this.  runBatch is a function in the same script and I need to get everything into variables to send to the output page containing all the info.  Maybe I can turn runBatch into a separate script and return the end time as an echo somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Memory:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

Next grep whatever you want,

Cpu, it is more complicated - [/proc/stat expained](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm)

Average load:

```
cat /proc/loadavg
```

For timing "runBatch" use

```
time runBatch
```

like

```
time sleep 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got the pid of your process (e.g. like [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216408/841108)) you can use (with [watch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) & [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) or [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)) the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) file system, e.g.

```
 watch cat /proc/$myPID/stat
```

(or use `/proc/$myPID/status` or `/proc/$myPID/statm`, or `/proc/$myPID/maps` for the address space, etc...)

BTW, to run batch jobs you should consider [batch](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/batch.htm) (and you might look into [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) to run things periodically)